# Pytest not picking up tests even with correct naming convention

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to test a class where I monkeypatch a variable within the class with another function stored in `conftest.py`, but none of the test are detected even with the correct naming convention of prefixing `test_` to the test name as well as the file name.

This is `conftest.py` in the root of `tests` directory.

```py
import pytest
from pathlib import Path
import spacy

# Pass path to staticdata to any test
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def get_staticdata_path():
    static_data_path = (
        Path(
            __file__,
        )
        .resolve()
        .parent
        / ".."
        / ".."
        / "staticdata"
    )
    return static_data_path

# Pass function that loads a spacy model based on data in staticdata 
# instead of downloading it everytime
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def load_spacy_model():
    static_data_path = get_staticdata_path()
    model_path = static_data_path / "en_core_web_sm"
    nlp = spacy.load(model_path)
    return nlp
```

This is the file that is not getting picked up for testing which is located at `tests/natural_language_processing/test_utils.py`

```py
import pytest
from omdenalore.natural_language_processing.utils import TextUtils


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "text,expected,exception",
    [
        # No inputs
        (None, None, Exception),
        (
            "This is a sample sentence, showing off the stop words filtration.",
            "This sample sentence, showing stop words filtration.",
            None,
        ),
    ],
)
def test_stop_word_removal(text, expected, exception, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(TextUtils.stop_word_removal, "nlp", load_spacy_model)
    with pytest.raises(exception):
        result = TextUtils.stop_word_removal(text)
        assert result == expected
```

Output when I run `pytest` at the root dir:

```
============================================================= test session starts =============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.11, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/yravindranath/OmdenaLore
collected 32 items                                                                                                                            

tests/computer_vision/test_IoU.py ...                                                                                                   [  9%]
tests/computer_vision/test_MSE.py ...                                                                                                   [ 18%]
tests/computer_vision/test_PSNR.py ...                                                                                                  [ 28%]
tests/computer_vision/test_RMSE.py ...                                                                                                  [ 37%]
tests/computer_vision/test_SSIM.py ...                                                                                                  [ 46%]
tests/datasets/test_download_datasets.py .....                                                                                          [ 62%]
tests/optical_character_recognition/test_pytesseract_ocr.py ............                                                                [100%]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_stop_word_removal` is declared as a fixture (`@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)`). It seems to be the reason why it is not detected as test.

The decorator `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)` declares a fixture that will be automatically *requested* by all the tests, see [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html).

Here is the way to declare the test method using the fixture `load_spacy_model`.

```py
def test_stop_word_removal(text, expected, exception, monkeypatch, load_spacy_model):
    monkeypatch.setattr(TextUtils.stop_word_removal, "nlp", load_spacy_model)
    # ...
```

Comment: Cool. You have either to request `load_spacy_model` in the test using it (i.e. declaring it as a`test_stop_word_removal` method parameter) or declare it to be loaded by default by using `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)` if you intend to use it in all the tests.

Comment: Thanks I have another issue with the monkeypatch but your answer solves this issue.